# Find $A$ if $B=A-A^T$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

Suppose $B=A-A^T$ and I know $B\in\mathbb R^{n\times n}$. What is a simple way to get $A$? And what if I have the constraint that $A_{ij}\ge 0$ $\forall i,j$?

Clarifications:

- $B$ is skew symmetric
- $a_{ii}$ (the diagonal elements of $A$) are zero

Comment: Not sure right away, but if you know $A+A^T$ as well, then you can do $$A=\frac{1}{2}(A-A^T)+\frac{1}{2}(A+A^T)$$

Comment: You can't solve for all the elements of $A$. In particular, its diagonal elements will be inaccessible because $B$ is skew-symmetric.

Comment: You can't. If $A$ is one solution, then $A+C$ is another for *any* symmetric matrix $C$, As $C=C^T$ it will cancel from $(A+C)-(A+C)^T$.

Comment: Of course, the skew-symmetric *part* of $A$ will be $\frac{1}{2}B$...

Comment: I added some clarifications which remove some ambiguities.

Answer (score 2):

If you only know $B$ then for the equation to have a solution, $B$ must be skew symmetric. 
$$\implies b_{ij}=a_{ij}-a_{ji} \forall i,j$$

Now you can pick many $a_{ij}, a_{ji}$ that satisfy this equation. One choice is $a_{ij}=k, a_{ji}=k-b_{ij}$. Similarly you can pick nearly anything for the non diagonal elements. For diagonals you can have any $a_{ii}=k 
\in \mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 2):

You can’t, not without further information.

Suppose that $B$ is :

$$
B=
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1\\
-1&0\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

NB : $B$ is antisymmetric from the given condition and therefore the leading diagonal is zero.

Then all we can deduce about $A$ is that it has the form :

$$
A=
\begin{bmatrix}
p&q+1\\
q&r\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Where $p$, $q$, and $r \in\mathbb{R}$

Even with the constraint, you are only requiring that $p, q, r > 0$, which doesn’t allow you to solve for them uniquely.